# nhibernate ISessionFactory for client-server software

Tags: c#, postgresql, nhibernate

I am new to `nhibernate` and I am building a client-server application. I've heard that to create a nhinernate `ISessionFactory` it's better if I create it only once. But it will impact the database as well ? or just the workstation where the software is running ? I am asking it because if it was 3-tier application, then I will have only one nhinernate but, as my application is client-server, the software will run on each workstation. So each workstation will create once a nhinernate `ISessionFactory`.

Answer (score 0):

No. It will not impact the database. Actually, there are a lot of reasons to keep a single instance of ISessionFactory. One of these main reasons is to help nhibernate know all the information about how it should access the database, I mean, how it should generate the queries to throughout `mappings` configurations.

From the [NHibernate Docs](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/)

> The internal state of a SessionFactory is immutable. Once it is
>   created this internal state is set. This internal state includes all
>   of the metadata about Object/Relational Mapping.

`ISessionFactory` will not conect on the database, it will provide instances of `Session` by `OpenSession()` method and the `Session` will conect for you.

Depending of the model you are mapping with NHibernate, starting an `ISessionFactory` can take a little bit time. There are some [pratices to improve the performance of the initialization](http://lucisferre.net/2009/06/18/speed-up-nhibernate-startup-with-object-serialization/) of `ISessionFactory`. If you implement it, remember to delete the serialization file if you change your mappings.